# Is link/PR juice being passed to CSS, favicon, thumbnail files?

Tags: seo, pagerank

Is link/PR juice being passed to CSS, favicon, thumbnail files?

If yes, how to combine `rel="icon"` or `rel="stylesheet"` with `nofollow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah- No. Only for content. Think pages and pages only.

Google designed PageRank to indicate what web pages are important. It is designed to valuate content, not ancillary resources that have no value of their own. Since it's inception, it has been expanded to include content resources such as PDF, word documents, spreadsheets and anything else that can be considered content but not extended to non-content elements.

Comment: Could you be more specific and give a little more explanation?

Comment: @CamSpy Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pagerank depends only on the contents in your webpages. Any stylesheet or script that you have added to enhance the look and feel of your webpage can't affect Google page rank. Because Stylesheets haven't any significance in determining the reliability of the content.